# Sort & filter Rails model by Select tag without ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Didn't find any clean and simple solution without Ajax for my problem.

The problem is – how to sort&filter any ActiveRecord models lists using `select` tag.

What I basically need is:

- browser opens new page with URL parameter updated when user selects another value
- all other url parameters stay untouched and i don't create URL from scratch

For example:

1. user goes on `/controller/action?sort=date&page=18&filter=A`
2. then he click on the drop-down list and changes the `filter` to `Z`
3. Huray1 user goes to `/controller/action?sort=date&page=18&filter=Z`
4. PS: my application doesn't care about any othe url parameters, controller, action etc. It just updates `filter` field and moves user there.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the method on your form tag to `"GET"` and use a nil URL to have it submit to the current location.

```
<%= form_tag nil, :method => 'GET' do %>
  ...
```

Then you can use javascript to submit the form when the user changes the selection of the drop-down.

Comment: Already tried this, empty action for form tag removes all other parameters except submitted one :(

Comment: You probably want to set the form fields according to the URL params.  That way the user sees which options have been selected and the values will get submitted again

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up with so far is to put all current params to hidden form fields and submit the form by JS code on select value change.